# Wordpress redirecting to wrong homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, xampp, bitnami, storefront

I worked for a few days on XAMPP with a wordpress platform. After I bought a domain, I decided to use Duplicator plugin to transfer my whole wordpress snap to the new server. Everything is working just fine except for one single thing: whenever I go to my website, instead of visiting the actual page that should be "www.example.com/welcome" it redirects automatically to "www.example.com/wordpress". I made some research about it and discovered that usually wp is installed in a wordpress directory, but I completely made sure that:

- on htaccess there is no /wordpress directory url
- on index.php there is no /wordpress directory url
- on wp-config there is no /wordpress directory both on SITE-URL and HOME
- made sure that on the wp-admin config panel in the General section, the URLs are both set to the root directory.

For some unexplicable reason, everything is working fine, www.example.com/shop works for example, but if I set from the customization panel a page like "www.example.com/dummy" as homepage, then THAT page won't be found because it automatically redirects "dummy" to "/wordpress" which of course does not exist. You can type www.example.com and be redirected to www.example.com/wordpress and the same thing happens if you type www.example.com/dummy, since now that should be the homepage.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening? I searched everywhere but I can't find an answer.

I'm using the Storefront theme and Woocommerce plugin if that might help.

Comment: Please also check  in your  wp-options table

Comment: Try it in incognito mode as well

Comment: OMG. The incognito mode worked. For some reasons opera was keeping me from realizing that it was my browser's fault.  I tried with firefox and it works, thank you SO MUCH. I spent the past hour on this.

Comment: Indeed, this is most likely caused by the HTTP cache of your browser. It can usually be disabled from the developer tools' options.